# FOSFacebookBunlde throws "Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 103" exception

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosfacebookbundle

Since I updated from symfony 2.0 to 2.1 I cannot login via Facebook.
Symfony redirects me to my login page and displays this error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 103

You can see my log file below:

```
[2012-11-19 09:17:48] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:48] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:48] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:49] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_facebook_security_check" (parameters: "_controller": "Strict\UserBundle\Controller\LoginController::loginFbAction", "_locale": "pl", "_route": "fos_facebook_security_check") [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:49] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest". [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:49] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.facebookId AS facebookId18, t0.name AS name19, t0.text AS text20, t0.location AS location21, t0.picturePath AS picturePath22, t0.www AS www23, t0.language AS language24, t0.facebookWww AS facebookWww25, t0.male AS male26, t0.reviewsCount AS reviewsCount27, t0.postsCount AS postsCount28, t0.emailEnabled AS emailEnabled29, t0.messagesEnabled AS messagesEnabled30, t0.wwwNofollow AS wwwNofollow31, t0.facebookWwwNofollow AS facebookWwwNofollow32, t0.yearBirth AS yearBirth33, t0.lastModified AS lastModified34, t0.picture_id AS picture_id35 FROM fos_user t0 WHERE t0.facebookId = ? LIMIT 1 ["000_facebook_id_here_0000"] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:51] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.username AS username1, t0.username_canonical AS username_canonical2, t0.email AS email3, t0.email_canonical AS email_canonical4, t0.enabled AS enabled5, t0.salt AS salt6, t0.password AS password7, t0.last_login AS last_login8, t0.locked AS locked9, t0.expired AS expired10, t0.expires_at AS expires_at11, t0.confirmation_token AS confirmation_token12, t0.password_requested_at AS password_requested_at13, t0.roles AS roles14, t0.credentials_expired AS credentials_expired15, t0.credentials_expire_at AS credentials_expire_at16, t0.id AS id17, t0.facebookId AS facebookId18, t0.name AS name19, t0.text AS text20, t0.location AS location21, t0.picturePath AS picturePath22, t0.www AS www23, t0.language AS language24, t0.facebookWww AS facebookWww25, t0.male AS male26, t0.reviewsCount AS reviewsCount27, t0.postsCount AS postsCount28, t0.emailEnabled AS emailEnabled29, t0.messagesEnabled AS messagesEnabled30, t0.wwwNofollow AS wwwNofollow31, t0.facebookWwwNofollow AS facebookWwwNofollow32, t0.yearBirth AS yearBirth33, t0.lastModified AS lastModified34, t0.picture_id AS picture_id35 FROM fos_user t0 WHERE t0.email = ? LIMIT 1 ["my_email_address_here"] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:52] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:52] doctrine.DEBUG: "ROLLBACK" [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:52] security.INFO: Authentication request failed: Notice: Array to string conversion in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php line 103 [] []
[2012-11-19 09:17:52] security.DEBUG: Redirecting to fos_user_security_login [] []
```

The two sql SELECT queries above doesn't cause any errors and return no results (checked in phpmyadmin).

Composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.0.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "facebook/php-sdk": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/facebook-bundle": "dev-master",        
    "besimple/i18n-routing-bundle": "dev-master",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

To be honest I don't know what can be wrong and how to find an error.
If you need some extra data/config files post a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have found the solution.
The problem is that Facebook doesn't return `picture` string properties to pass to `setFBData` in `User` entity.

There was `picture` string property that contained image url. Now it contain:

> string; If the "October 2012 Breaking Changes" migration setting is enabled for your app, this field will be an object with the url and is_silhouette fields; is_silhouette is true if the user has not uploaded a profile picture

My setFBdata look like this:

```
public function setFBData($fbdata)
{
    ...
    if (isset($fbdata['picture']))
    {
        $this->setPicturePath($fbdata['picture']);
    }

}
```

As you can see it was trying to set object/array to string field.